# Migration from CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet to CXFServlet with Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, web-services, cxf

I'm attempting to migrate from CXF restful services using the Non-Spring servlet to CXFServlet. I'm using CXF 2.7 and Spring 4.1. The existing system is pretty large, so I'd like to minimize making changes to the individual services.

In Web.XML I've added:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/ApplicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

and

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>cxf-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.myapp.MyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

The individual services are added in MyApplication and look like this:

```
@Path("service")
public class MyService
```

With the usual annotations on the methods. The result is that everything compiles and runs without error, but the restful services are simply not found. I've seen examples that place all the services in the bean tag in the ApplicationContext.xml, or that add annotations to all the services, but I feel like there is a probably a way to register the services in java without going through that.